# angular4 directive not working inside HTML SPAN tag

Tags: html, angular

I have written a directive in angular4, which works on input fields.
When I apply that on SPAN tag, it is not working.
Can we apply the directives on SPAN TAG, or is there any work around.

```
<span dirTemp>45789</span>
```

dirTemp actually corrects the value to 45,789

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, OnInit, AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked, AfterContentChecked } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:directive-selector
  selector: '[dirTemp ]',
})

export class FormatterDirective implements AfterViewChecked {
  private el: HTMLInputElement;

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private cPipe: MyPipe
  ) {
    this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
  }

  // ngOnInit() {
  //  this.el.value = this.cPipe.transform(this.el.value);
  // }

  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    this.el.value = this.cPipe.parse(this.el.value);
    this.el.value = this.cPipe.transform(this.el.value);
  }

  @HostListener('focus', ['$event.target.value'])
  onFocus(value) {
    console.log('in formatter directive:', value);
    this.el.value = this.cPipe.parse(value);
  }

  @HostListener('focusout', ['$event.target.value'])
  onFocusout(value) {
    this.el.value = this.cPipe.transform(value);
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you please add some code so we could help you out better?

Comment: I added my  directive, may be I need to add another hostlistener. I am apply the directive to a column in the table. The TD value is inside <span dirTemp ></span>

Comment: A span doesn't fire `focusout` by default. You should post your html structure to get more context on what you are trying to do

Comment: @Pierre, ok. My html is very simple, In a table, I have <tr><td>  <span dirTemp>45789</span>

Answer (score 2):

**Workaround:** `span` doesn't have `value` but has `innerText` or `innerHTML`. So, On `ngOnInit` you can do:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    if(this.el.tagName.toUpperCase() !== 'INPUT') {
      //  Apply your tranform here:
      var originalValue =  this.el.innerText;
      this.el.innerText = this.cPipe.transform(originalValue);
    }
  }
```

Comment: @user1015388 You have that defined in your constructor. `this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;`

Comment: I tried to use this, this.el.innerText gives empty value

Comment: Yes, I figured out that my value with in SPAN TAG is dynamic with in {{}}. SO its empty. How can we get tat

Comment: I need to use afterviewchecked, as my data renders after the view is complete. Thanks